# File encoded as UCS-2 Little Endian reports 2x too many lines to Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I was processing several txt files with a simple Java program, and the first step of my process is counting the lines of each file:

```
int count = 0;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile)); // myFile is the txt file in question
while (br.readLine() != null) {
    count++;
}
```

For one of my files, Java was counting exactly twice as many lines as there really were!  This was confusing me greatly at first.  I opened each file in Notepad++ and could see that the mis-counting file ended every line in exactly the same way as the other files, with a CR and LF.  I did a little more poking around and noticed that all my "ok" files were ANSI encoded, and the one problem file was encoded as UCS-2 Little Endian (which I know nothing about).  I got these files elsewhere, so I have no idea why the one was encoded that way, but of course switching it to ANSI fixed the issue.

But now curiosity remains.  Why was the encoding causing a double line count report?

Thanks!

Comment: investigate further by checking what readLine() returns

Comment: It would really help if you could say what's in the "blah blah" given that it's entirely possile that's where the error is...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good comment.  From java documentation: _Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed._  I did notice that if I try to output what is read from the UCS-2 encoded file, it outputs a garbled box character instead of the CR.

Comment: UCS-2 is a encoding similar (and predecessor) to UTF-16

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point.  I updated the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple: if you apply the wrong encoding when reading UCS-2 (or UTF-16) text (e.g. ANSI, or any 8-bit encoding), then every second character is a 0x0. This then breaks the CR-LF to CR-0-LF, which is seen as two line changes (one for CR and one for LF).

Comment: This seems like the right answer, and I thank you (any chance your username is related to the American band?).  But... I am still a bit confused.  If this is the case, when I output what Java read in from the file, why aren't all those zeroes visible?  Actually, maybe I can answer that myself since it appears the file that Java outputs is the same encoding as the input.  So the zeroes remain hidden to me and only Java notices them?  Is there any way I can get Java to output it with all the zeroes and extra "lines"?

Comment: I guess if I could get Java to output ANSI after reading the UCS-2, then it should theoretically output all those null characters, right?  But the way I'm doing it currently, Java outputs in the same format it read it in (UCS-2).  Which is something even more confusing, since it apparently reads the 16-bit file from an 8-bit mindset and then puts it back out as 16-bit, so I don't actually see what it was reading.

Comment: It doesn't read UCS-2, that's the point. If you specify the right encoding for reading the file and then write it out with the ANSI encoding (ISO 8859-1), then you'd be performing a conversion like you manually did it with your editor.

Comment: So when Java is reading the UCS-2 with all the interleaved null chars, and thinks it is reading ANSI, then it does not actually record all those null characters?  When it outputs a record of every character it read, there are no null characters listed, even though it counted them in my count lines procedure.  I'm afraid my question is starting to sounds stupid... I guess I'm just wondering why if Java recognizes null characters it doesn't record them with the readLine() method, since I believe there is a way to store a null character.  Maybe that is an intentional choice though.

Comment: I'm not sure how the ANSI encoding reads 0x0 characters, those are a bit special anyways since they are used as terminators in C strings and therefore usually not used in regular text. That said, I'm not sure what you mean with "when it outputs a record of every character it read", is this some code that computes statistics of the characters read?

Comment: Yes, sorry... part of my trouble-shooting earlier was printing each `readLine()` (my "output record") to see what it contained, and after you clued me in to all the extra null chars I started wondering why I didn't see them in my output record, even when viewed in an advanced text reader.  But yeah, you may be right about ANSI encoding possibly ignoring them.  I could have sworn I'd seen them before as NUL in Notepad++, but I could be wrong and it's not really that important.  Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: Notepad++ would probably show them as NUL if it was using the wrong encoding to read the text, but it's usually smart enough to detect this pattern and therefore switch to the correct (UCS-2 or more likely UTF-16) encoding. Is there an advanced open in Notepad++ where you can specify the encoding to be used? Try this and specify ANSI, you should start seeing your NULs then.

Comment: I tried that and couldn't get it to work, BUT I do have a Hex viewer plugin for N++ which did of course show all the 00's every other character.  So, that is something. :-)

Comment: Encodings are always fun... I guess the lesson you can learn from this is that you need to always used the correct encoding when dealing with text, especially when reading text. This is also why XML for instance specifies the encoding early in the text so that the parser can switch to the correct encoding before any special characters are encountered. That plus some BOM handling and heuristics for BOM-less files allows for quite good detection of commonly used encodings.

Comment: I found out one more fun thing.  The Java output file contained the same FFFE header (for UCS) as the input file did, since it read those FF and FE literally I'd assume.  So if I take that into Notepad++ and use Hex plugin to delete the header... BAM!  All the NUL chars are visible as I had hoped to see.  But if I change encoding to ANSI without removing the header first, N++ is smart enough to do the conversion properly because it sees the header, and therefore removes all the NUL's.

Comment: This FFFE "header" is the so-called [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) which I mentionned in my previous comment. It helps identify the encoding used as well as whether it is [little or big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 9):

This is the problem:

```
new FileReader(myFile)
```

That will use the platform default encoding. Don't do that. Use

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile), encoding)
```

where `encoding` is the appropriate encoding for the file. You've got to use the right encoding, or you won't read the file properly. Unfortunately of course that relies on you *knowing* the encoding...

EDIT: To answer the question of why the lines were double counted rather than just "how do I fix it", see Lucero's answer :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I changed the accepted answer to this post.  The one below helped me understand what went wrong, but this one helped me understand how to make it right.  I did not realize you could add encoding to a FileInputStream constructor.  Good stuff!

Comment: @The111: It's not the FileInputStream constructor - FileInputStream deals with *binary* data. It's InputStreamReader, which is converting a *binary* `InputStream` to a *text* `Reader` - so that's the natural place to put an encoding.

Comment: Thanks again, it's a bit late and I am not reading clearly. :-)

Comment: While Jon of course has the right fix, I understand that the *question* was why double lines were counted.

Comment: @Lucero: Have added an edit to refer to your answer for that side of things.

Comment: Sigh... answer changed back.  You are correct Lucero, you did more directly answer my Q... I guess Jon just wowed me more with something I wasn't expecting.  I'd accept both your answers if I could. :-)